# How to extract CPGZ File

Tags: 14.04, file-format

I have a file with cpgz extension and I want to extract it on Ubuntu 14.04. Is there any command that I can extract easily ?

Comment: Those file are php error messages file, and they are not zipped and you can not extract them.  ***I think***

Comment: No, that is not php error messages file. I get this file from MAC OS X and It contains android sdk files

Comment: Open the terminal and then type as "unzip" leave a space then drap the file in extension .cpgz format into the terminal and press enter to find the file. Hope this helps !

Comment: You could use the `file` command to see what the file really is. Read `man file`.

Answer (score 6):

Just to make things clearer: the answer by @Emre Koç works, but it might not be obvious where your archive name goes.

```
gzip -cd ARCHIVENAME.cpgz | cpio -idmv
```

Replace `ARCHIVENAME` with the name of your archive. Remember to first `cd` into the directory where your archive is located.

Answer (score 3):

I extracted with `gzip -cd foo.cpio.gz | cpio -idmv`
Code is taken from [here](https://superuser.com/a/31080/383614)

Comment: Your question says the file has a `.cpgz` extension; your answer says it has `.cpio.gz`.

Comment: cpgz is compressed format of cpio.gz. There is no difference if you want to extract both of them

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the file without .gz and open it. Could be that there is no compressed file in the first place.